# Stuck with httpclient.execute(httppost) at android 4.2.2 sdk

Tags: android, http, client

Please anybody can help? I learn to create a login app with android. And I stuck with `httpclient.execute` result always null n skip to catch after `httpclient.execute`

This my code :

```
try {
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/myandroidsite/user_validate.php");

        //Add data
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserMail",usr.trim()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",pass.trim()));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    //Execute HTTP Post Request
    respone = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    inputstream = respone.getEntity().getContent();

    data = new byte[256];

    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int len = 0;
    while(-1 != (len = inputstream.read(data)))
    {
      buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
    }
      inputstream.close();
    }
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: where is it null, post the Logcat

Comment: I guess it's NetworkOnMainThreadException? Since on android version 3.0 and up, if you try to do any network operation on main thread, that exception will be thrown by the OS. So you need to create a thread for httpclient to execute your http post request.

Comment: thanks for response Kevin & tyczj, btw can you teach me how to create a thread?